# Parse data from wiki XML dump with C#

Tags: c#, wikipedia, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api, wikimedia-dumps

I'm trying to extract the aliases of Foreign minister in respective countries. I found the information [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_minister) at Wikipedia.

I also found the dump XML file and the link for XML representation of "Foreign_minister" page is:

```
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Foreign_minister&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content
```

Now I'm trying to get this page out of XML dump in C#. I'll parse that XML then to get the information out of it. I'm blocked in fetching anything out of XML dump and I don't know how to interact with it to get the respective page in XML format out of it. Any leads?

Comment: You forgot to specify format  **&format=xml**
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&titles=Foreign_minister&rvprop=timestamp|user|comment|content&format=xml

Comment: Ok, do you know how to get this from dump with C#?

Comment: Actually - yes :-), the content is JSON. To parse JSON, you can use parser from newtonsoft http://www.newtonsoft.com/json or just  parse manually, the format is very easy. Sorry for previous answer, it's typical Mathematician's answer, i did not inspected the resulting xml

Comment: I'm not concerned about parsing XML or JSON, what I'm really looking for is the way to interact with dump XML which I got from here - http://dumps.wikimedia.org/enwiki/20151102/.

Comment: gz, bz2 or 7z format?